# how to convert a complex array to object

Tags: javascript

I have array like this

```
    [
  'A (1)',
  'B (2)',
  'C (3)',
  'D (6)',
  'E (0)',
  'F(0)'
]
```

I want convert above array to object like this \

```
  { A:1,B:2,C:3,D:6,E:0,F:0 }
```

what is the best way to convert

Comment: You should be sharing your code that you have tried and mention what error you were getting or what is not working with your code.

Answer (score 2):

You can map your array elements into *entries* format `[key, value]` and pass that into [Object.fromEntries()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/fromEntries).

One option for extracting the *keys* and *values* from your string would be to use a regular expression.

```js
const arr = [
  'A (1)',
  'B (2)',
  'C (3.14159)',
  'non-conformant value just for fun',
  'D (-6)',
  'E (0)',
  'F(0)'
]

const rx = /^(\w+) ?\((-?\d+(\.\d+)?)\)$/
const obj = Object.fromEntries(
  arr.map(val => val.match(rx)?.slice(1))
    .filter(entry => !!entry)
    .map(([k, v]) => [k, Number(v)])
)

console.log(obj)
```

This will handle any set of *word characters* as the key and any numeric expression as the value.

Comment: damn that's nice. upvoted!

Comment: wow, thanks dude

Comment: `val => +val.match(rx)?.slice(1)` and the output would be as required :p

Comment: @Bravo and here I was trying to keep it flexible. Looks like I made it too flexible. That won't work though as `val` is an array there

Comment: the mistake was right, my fix was wrong :p didn't read the code very well at all :p

Answer (score 0):

`Array.reduce` implementation

```js
var regExp = /\(([^)]+)\)/;
const data = [
  'A (1)',
  'B (2)',
  'C (3)',
  'D (6)',
  'E (0)',
  'F(0)'
];
const output = data.reduce((acc, curr) => {
  acc[curr[0]] = +regExp.exec(curr)[1];
  return acc;
}, {});
console.log(output)
```

Comment: convert the values to numbers and it would be as required

Answer (score 0):

// this should work given that the second last position always contains the digit. Use regex to extract the number value if this isn't working for you.

```
let arr = [
    'A (1)',
    'B (2)',
    'C (3)',
    'D (6)',
    'E (0)',
    'F(0)'
]

let modArr = new Map(
    arr.map((item) => [item[0], parseInt(item[item.length-2])]
    )
)
let obj = Object.fromEntries(modArr)
console.log(obj)
```

Comment: odd way of doing it, assumes single letter and single digit - but at least it outputs the values as Numbers

Comment: Right. The purpose was mainly to demonstrate how to convert that array to object. Separating the keys & values can be done with regex anyway he/she wants it to.

Answer (score 0):

```js
var disp = document.getElementById("response");
var x = [
    'A (1)',
    'B (2)',
    'C (3)',
    'D (6)',
    'E (0)',
    'F(0)'
];
var objdata = (arr) => {
    var obj = {};
    arr.forEach((a) => {
        var indArr = a.replace(' ', '').split('(');
        obj[indArr[0]] = indArr[1].replace(')', '');
    });
    return obj;
}
disp.innerHTML = JSON.stringify(objdata(x))
```

```html
<span id="response"></span>
```